# Как запустить бота

Tags: python, telebot

Друг поделился ботом в тг файлами питон. Подскажите пожалуйста как его вообще запустить

Comment: @HappeTown, приложите файл, код? Уточните у друга что он использует за сервер. Мы бы рады помочь, но вы не даете нам такой возможности

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужно создать свой шаблон бота в телеграмме bot-father. Потом где находится поле, возможно по названием  `token = TeleBot(сюда вставь свой код бота выданный bot father)`

Comment: "Шаблон", "код" - пишите "токен" и не путайте человека )

Answer (score 1):

Гайд для чайника:

1. Редактируешь бота под себя (например, изменяешь токен бота, различные id), если необходимо
2. Размещаешь бота на любом удобном тебе хостинге
3. Запускаешь бота

Разместить можно и не на хостинге, а локально, но тогда бот будет работать только тогда, когда у тебя запущен бот (aka включен комп). Например, можешь скопировать код бота в любой редактор кода (например, PyCharm или VS Code) и в консоли пишешь `python3 namebot.py`, заменив `namebot.py` на название файла бота. Перед этим нужно установить на ПК библиотеки, которые указаны в начале кода.

На хостинге флоу по запуску примерно такой же, но для запуска бота нужно будет создать screen (модуль, который создаёт параллельные рабочие столы) – тут уже погугли.